# How to display these php search results in bootstrap 3 tables

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display the information in the database using php but need the table to be styled using bootstrap 3 and not the default html table tag. I need assistance to fix this challenge so that i can have a better understanding of how to display search results using php. Thanks

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oas");
if ($connect) {

    $search = "";

    $query = "SELECT distinct(M.`s_id`) as `s_id`,
                     M.`s_mark`,
                     U.`s_name`
                     FROM `t_usermark` as M
                    JOIN `t_user_data` as U on M.s_id = U.s_id  WHERE `s_name` like '%$search%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if ($result) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            echo "
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Mark</th>
                        </tr>
                    ";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $id = $row['s_id'];
                $mark = $row['s_mark'];
                $name = $row['s_name'];

                echo "
                            <tr>
                                <td>$id</td>
                                <td>$name</td>
                                <td>$mark</td>
                            </tr>
                        ";

                // echo "<p>$id</p><p>$mark</p><p>$name</p>";
            }

        } else {
            echo "No results";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($connect);
    }
} else {
    echo "Database connection failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: https://www.quackit.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_3/tutorial/bootstrap_tables.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Not going to do it for you but, Add the class table to the table tag then it will be styled using the Bootstrap styling.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <title>Search result  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "oas");
if ($connect) {

$search = "";

$query = "SELECT distinct(M.`s_id`) as `s_id`,
                     M.`s_mark`,
                     U.`s_name`
                     FROM `t_usermark` as M
                    JOIN `t_user_data` as U on M.s_id = U.s_id  WHERE `s_name` like '%$search%'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

if ($result) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Mark</th>
                        </tr>
                    ";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row['s_id'];
            $mark = $row['s_mark'];
            $name = $row['s_name'];
                echo '<tr>
      <th scope="row">'.$id.'</th>
      <td>'.$name.'</td>
      <td>'.$mark.'</td>
    </tr>';
            }

            echo '
</tbody>
</table>';
        } else {
            echo "No results";
        }

        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_error($connect);
    }
} else {
    echo "Database connection failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: 1) just adding the bootstrap CSS file to the page does not, by itself, make the table be formatted in bootstrap style. 2) OP specifically asked about bootstrap 3, not 4.